# How can I share session data across web methods in C#

Tags: asp.net

How can I share session data across web methods. I have already used [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]above web method, but After setting the data from one webmethod, I'm getting Session null when I access it from other web method.

Comment: please give some more code of your methods, how o call them, the web.config about session...

Comment: have you enabled session state in web config?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
```